# Plot and visualize results of clustering as a network graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I'm experimenting with various clustering algorithms and string distance metrics in Python, with the end goal of clustering a list of strings according to various distance metrics such as Levenshtein, Jaro, etc (each string normally has 1 or 2 words).

I've build code for computing distances between strings according to different distance metrics (using jellyfish package), and to cluster them with different algorithms provided by the sklearn.cluster package. Here's some sample code for Jaro distance and MeanShift clustering:

```
tokens = np.array(["test1", "test2", "test3", "cat", "cat food", "apple", "apple pie"])

distances = -1 * np.array([[jellyfish.jaro_distance(w1, w2) for w1 in tokens] for w2 in tokens])

meanshift = sklearn.cluster.MeanShift()
meanshift.fit(distances)

clusters = dict()
key = 0
for cluster_id in np.unique(meanshift.labels_):
    cluster = np.unique(tokens[np.nonzero(meanshift.labels_ == cluster_id)])
    clusters[key] = cluster.tolist()
    key += 1

plot_clusters(clusters, ...)
```

Now I'd like to plot/visualize/save the results of clustering preferably as a network graph similar to this one [1]. I would be happy with a simple visualization that makes it easy to see (and count) the different clusters. That's why I build just a dictionary with the cluster elements. However, it would be nice if the visualization would take into account the distance between data points as calculated beforehand. Either way would work fine for me. I just want some nice visualizations to go along with the analyses of the actual clusters.

Does anyone have some ideas or pointers on how to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

[1] https://www.kdnuggets.com/wp-content/uploads/k-means-datasci.jpg

Disclaimer: I'm new to python and to machine learning in general

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing the distances yet, but you could do some colored scatter plot like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

plt.figure()
clustercount = len(clusters)
color=iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,clustercount)))

for cl in clusters:    
    c=next(color)
    x = # x data of your cluster here
    y = # y data of your cluster here
    label = # label of your cluster here

    plt.scatter(x, y, color=c, label=label)

plt.xlabel('X');
plt.ylabel('Y');
plt.legend(loc=2);
plt.show()
```

This will visualize the clusters in different colors so you can see and count them easily

Maybe you can access the cluster centers via meanshift.cluster_centers_. If so you could plot them too with a static color to visualize the distances.